# Is it possible to get data from excel file and create a pie chart and display on a sharepoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, reporting-services, excel-services, excel-web-access-webpart

Can we create a pie chart using excel reporting service.
I have a excel file (.xlsx) on my SharePoint document library.
I want to use excel data and create a pie chart but don't want to create this pie chart in excel.

I have created a pie chart in excel and show this chart on my site using excel web access web part but my client don't want to use this approach. Please suggest any different way to create pie chart from excel and display on web site.

**Is it possible to pick the data from a excel file (.xlsx), generate report and display it on SharePoint site.**

Answer (score 1):

1. You can save your excel document as an XPS file.  Use "Save As" in Excel.
2. Upload saved XPS file to your SharePoint site.
3. Copy URL of XPS to text file.
4. On SharePoint site, add a page viewer web part to page.  Add copied URL to link block and click Ok or Apply.  Depending on size of the chart(s), you will need to adjust the height and/or width of web part under Appearance.

Comment: Thanks for replay. I want to create pie chart using excel report services(not in excel), Using this way I can only show the existing chart.

Comment: I think you need to use Dashboard Designer.